# PHP error message showing when I try to check a value from database table

Tags: php

I am using this PHPAuth from this github link: https://github.com/PHPAuth/PHPAuth. Using this tutorial I am trying to make a registration system.

Now, I am getting following error message when I check a field value already exists in the database table:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function count() on boolean ........... Stack trace: #0 ...........: Validate->check(Array, Array) #1 {main} thrown in ......\admin\classes\Validate.php on line 41
```

I am checking with following code:

```
$check = $this->_db->get($rule_value, array($item, '=', $value));
if($check->count()) {
    $this->addError("{$item} already exists.");
}
break;
```

**DB.php page:**

```
<?php

class DB {
    private static $_instance = null;
    private $_pdo,
            $_query,
            $_error = false,
            $_results,
            $_count = 0;

    private function __construct() {
        try {
            $this->_pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=' . Config::get('mysql/host') . ';dbname=' . Config::get('mysql/database'), Config::get('mysql/username'), Config::get('mysql/password'));
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            die($e->getMessage());
        }
    }

    public static function getInstance() {
        if(!isset(self::$_instance)) {
            self::$_instance = new DB();
        }
        return self::$_instance;
    }

    public function query($sql, $params = array()) {
        $this->_error = false;

        if($this->_query = $this->_pdo->prepare($sql)) {
            $x = 1;
            if(count($params)) {
                foreach($params as $param) {
                    $this->_query->bindValue($x, $param);
                    $x++;
                }
            }

            if($this->_query->execute()) {
                $this->_results = $this->_query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
                $this->_count = $this->_query->rowCount();
            } else {
                $this->_error = true;
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function action($action, $table, $where = array()) {
        if(count($where) === 3) {
            $operators = array('=', '>', '<', '>=', '<=');

            $field = $where[0];
            $operator = $where[1];
            $value = $where[2];

            if(in_array($operator, $operators)) {
                $sql = "{$action} FROM {$table} WHERE {$field} {$operator} ?";

                if(!$this->query($sql, array($value))->error()) {
                    return $this;
                }
            }

        }

        return false;
    }

    public function insert($table, $fields = array()) {
        $keys = array_keys($fields);
        $values = null;
        $x = 1;

        foreach($fields as $field) {
            $values .= '?';
            if ($x < count($fields)) {
                $values .= ', ';
            }
            $x++;
        }

        $sql = "INSERT INTO {$table} (`" . implode('`, `', $keys) . "`) VALUES ({$values})";

        if(!$this->query($sql, $fields)->error()) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public function update($table, $id, $fields) {
        $set = '';
        $x = 1;

        foreach($fields as $name => $value) {
            $set .= "{$name} = ?";
            if($x < count ($fields)) {
                $set .= ', ';
            }
            $x++;
        }

        $sql = "UPDATE {$table} SET {$set} WHERE id = {$id}";

        if(!$this->query($sql, $fields)->error()) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public function delete($table, $where) {
        return $this->action('DELETE ', $table, $where);
    }

    public function get($table, $where) {
        return $this->action('SELECT *', $table, $where);
    }

    public function results() {
        return $this->_results;
    }

    public function first() {
        $data = $this->results();
        return $data[0];
    }

    public function count() {
        return $this->_count;
    }

    public function error() {
        return $this->_error;
    }
}
```

Is there anything I am doing wrong? How can I solve it?

Comment: Your `get()` method seem to return `false` instead of `$this`. Start by debugging it, follow the call flow, dump the arguments and check where in the chain it fails. Basically, do some basic debugging. My suggestion would actually be to use one of all the tried and tested db-libraries that already exist.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Your code almost assumes that everything is going to work.  If there are any problems at all, it just returns false - no errors,no indication of what has gone wrong.  If you want to develop a useful database class, make sure it generates errors that would help you find the problems.